Hypothesis testing with unknown covariance matrix under the alternative hypothesis
I am trying to solve a binary hypothesis testing problem of the form:
$H_1 : \mathbf{y} = \theta \cdot \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{n}$
$H_0 : \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{n}$
where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ under $H_1$, $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1)$ and $\mathbf{n} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0)$. We assume that the the random vectors $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ but $\theta$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1$ are unknown.
The solution to this problem is simple, i.e., I know that the generalized likelihood-ratio test (GLRT) is asymptotically optimal. It is also straightforward to find the MLE of $\theta$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1$ under $H_1$.
My question is the following:
What is the asymptotic distribution of the log-likelihood under both hypotheses? I know that Wilks' theorem asserts that
$H_1 : T_{GLRT} \sim \chi^{2}_{r}(\lambda)$
$H_0 : T_{GLRT} \sim \chi^{2}_{r}$
How can I determine what $r$ and $\lambda$ are?

Can I treat $\theta$ as the unknown parameter and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1$ as a nuisance parameter only under $H_1$, so that $r=1$ and $\lambda$ is the Fisher information of $\theta$ evaluated at $\theta = 0$, $\mathbf{I}(\theta = 0)$?

Do I have to treat both $\theta$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1$ as unknown parameters so that $r = 1 + d^2$ and $\lambda = \mathbf{I}(\theta = 0, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1 = \boldsymbol{0}_{d \times d})$?


Any help, suggestions and references will be appreciated greatly!
Edit: 1. I have modified the expressions involving the definitions of the hypotheses due to a lack of clarity.

The problem isn't identifiable in $(\theta,\Sigma_1)$. The covariance of $\theta x$ is $\theta^2\Sigma_1$ and you can only estimate this product not the two individually. So why not get rid of $\theta$ altogether?

I was using this specific formulation so that I can reformulate the hypothesis testing problem as:  $H_1: \theta \neq 0, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1$ is a nuisance parameter and $H_0: \theta = 0$. If I treat the unknown covariance matrix as a nuisance parameter, I can use the chi-squared distribtuion with a single degree of freedom. I hope this makes sense. Thanks!


Should your hypotheses have a y= or something in there? Expressions aren't hypotheses. It seems like saying "$H_0: 100$ vs $H_1:$ not $100$", it's missing mention of the thing its talking about there.   2. However, I'm curious why you didn't simply begin with the more conventional formulation in your comment instead.


Thanks for pointing it out. I've modified it based on your suggestion. I am not sure if the expression in the comments is the right way to formulate the hypotheses, which is why I did not include it in the original post.
